# Remap CTRL-x in insert mode

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I want to remap `<C-x>` in insert mode (I do not use the completion commands via this key). This is what I tried:

```
inoremap <C-x> <Esc> :x <Enter>
```

```
inoremap <C-x> <C-o> :x
```

Both variants are accepted by vim, but have no effect. When I execute `:imap <C-x>` I get:

`<C-X> * <C-R>=<SNR>27_ManualCompletionEnter()<CR>`.

I also tried to remove the default mapping:

```
iunmap <C-x>
```

which returns `E474: Invalid argument`.

So it seems that `<C-x>` is kind-of hard wired into vim and cannot be remapped. Is this correct or is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `:verbose imap <C-x>`; I doubt that mapping is coming from Vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `<C-X>` mapping is created by the [Supertab plugin](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab).

I'm not sure off the top of my head whether overwriting it will break that plugin, but you can test it out by setting up your mapping *after* Supertab has loaded.

One way to add this to your configuration is to use a [VimEnter autocommand](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter), which runs after the rest of the startup has completed. Add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
augroup MyCTRLX
  autocmd VimEnter * inoremap <c-x> <Esc>:x<Enter>
augroup END
```

Comment: Indeed!

Last set from ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/supertab/plugin/supertab.vim line 974

However, the autocommand doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, I just commented out the mapping in supertab, I'm not using it anyway. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Correction: while commenting out that line makes `c-x` working, it destroys supertab, it doesn't work anymore w/o it. So, I'll find another key for the purpose.